# JMH parameters from a file

Tags: java, jmh

I want to benchmark a program (using JMH) that reads data from a file and then measure the performance.
The name of files are stored as a list. The problem is that `@Param` only takes constant expressions, so in a way it means that I need to statically encode all the file names in `@Param`, which does not look good.

Is there another way, to run a benchmark for different files without static encoding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use the Java API, as [every JMH sample shows](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/1ba1bb91b83c/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_27_Params.java):

```
Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
        .include(JMHSample_27_Params.class.getSimpleName())
        .param("arg", "41", "42")
        .build();
new Runner(opt).run();
```